# Rackspace: installing mail and web server applications on the same server

Tags: web-server, rackspace, email-server

I've set up a web server on a Rackspace cloud server, and that is running fine and doing everything I need.

Now I am trying to figure out how to add the ability to send and receive e-mail. I've found a bunch of great tutorials on "how to set up a mail server," but I can't figure out whether it is possible to set up a mail server on the web server.

Is this possible? If so, generally speaking, how is it done? If not, do I need to just create a separate server as my mail server? Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly run a mail server and a webserver on the same Cloud Server.

One quick note if you're going to run an SMTP server: all Cloud Server IPs are by default included in the Spamhaus PBL (public block list), to avoid abuse by people inadvertently running insecure relays.  When you're ready to install your mail server, just to go http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso, put in your server's IP, and go through the steps to opt out of the block list so that people using the PBL service can receive your mail.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can be done, just install whatever mail server you want to use. There's no extra trickery involved.